# Design pattern for attribute wrapper in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, design-patterns, activerecord

I am looking for the right way to implement the following in Ruby on Rails 5.1:

I have an ActiveRecord **Platform** with the attribute `structure_xml` of type *LONGTEXT*. It contains pure XML. I would like to add a wrapper with helper methods to query the XML (using Nokogiri), e.g. to find certain nodes or to validate it.

**My current solution**

A non-ActiveRecord model **Structure** implements the required methods:

```
def Structure   
  def initialize(xml)
    @xml_root = Nokogiri::XML(xml).root
  end

  def get_node_by_id(node_id)
    @xml_root.xpath(".//Node[@id='#{node_id}']").first
  end
  ...
end
```

The ActiveRecord model initialises this model if needed:

```
class Platform < ApplicationRecord
  attr_accessor :structure

  def structure
    @structure || (@structure = Structure.new(structure_xml))
  end
  ...
end
```

It works, but it does not seem ideal to me. What would be the right approach to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be on right path. I would do probably the same with slight changes:

```
class Platform < ApplicationRecord
  delegate :xml_root, :my_method1, :my_method2, to: :structure

  def structure
    @structure ||= Structure.new(structure_xml)
  end
  ...
end
```

[`delegate`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Module.html#method-i-delegate) allows you to call the actions defined in another object without having to navigate through it.

You create modules only when you require namespace, same methods in more than one class, and when those methods are independent of an object of a class.

Answer (score 1):

I believe, Rails way would be to introduce a DSL like that (not tested, but it should work out of the box):

```
module Structured
  def self.extended base
    base.send :define_method, :structure do
      @structure ||= {}
    end
  end
  def structured(*fields)
    fields.each do |field|
      define_method "#{field}_structure" do
        structure[field] ||= Structure.new(public_send field)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

somewhere in initializers:

```
ApplicationRecord.extend Structured
```

and in your `Platform` (assuming it has a field `data` containing the raw xml):

```
class Platform < ApplicationRecord
  structured :data

  def print_it_out
    data_structure.get_node_by_id(3)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it's very close to what I am looking for. Currently I include `ActiveModel::Validations` in **Structure** to validate its integrity. How would you implement validation in your case? A method `valid?` in the module which gets called from a custom validator in the ApplicationRecord?

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you might automate this process with `self.validate :data, ->(v) { v.valid? }` line directly inside `fields.each` inside `structured` DSL. That way, the line `structured :data` inside the `ApplicationRecord`, will grant the record with this particular validator.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into the [Presenter](http://www.bacancytechnology.com/blog/ruby-on-rails-patterns-decorator-vs-presenter) or [Decorator](http://ieftimov.com/decorators-and-presenters) design pattern.

> ### Decorator
>
> A decorator resembles functionality of inheritance that we find in
>   many object oriented programming languages. It allows adding of
>   non-generic methods to define contextual objects which already possess
>   all features of any common entity. Like Mercedes brand’s motorcars
>   hold advance facilities on top of typical automobile machines.
>
> ### Presenter
>
> A presenter is a type or subset of decorator itself. It is
>   close to view model of MVC architecture. Presenters are composite
>   objects and we feed multiple options to it. It renders desired outcome
>   based on successful matching of condition.
>   The main objective of presenters is to put logic out of the view.

At least I'm pretty sure that's what you need but the decorator pattern might also be what you're looking for, the links has some basic info on both of them.